# Looking for improvements for the given code snippet using java and stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The below code snippet tries to add to a list that has pairs of string and double, from a given list. I have done this using java and stream API. But I am not sure this is the best way to do it. I think we can optimize the implementation using the streaming API itself. Please suggest improvements.

```
protected List<Pair<String, Double>> extractPlannedMaterials(List<ProductionDataSummaryDTO> productionData) {
    List<Pair<String, Double>> plannedMaterials = new LinkedList<>();

    productionData.forEach(data -> {
        data.getDailyProductionDatas().forEach(dailyData -> {

            String partNumber = dailyData.getProduct().getPartNumber();
            double sum = dailyData.getLineDatas().stream().mapToDouble(LineDataDTO::getPlannedQuantity).sum();

            if(plannedMaterials.stream().anyMatch(pair -> partNumber.equals(pair.getLeft()))) {
                Double existingValue = plannedMaterials.stream().filter(pair -> partNumber.equals(pair.getLeft()))
                    .findFirst().get().getRight();

                plannedMaterials.stream().filter(pair -> partNumber.equals(pair.getLeft()))
                    .findFirst().get().setValue(sum + existingValue);

            } else {
                plannedMaterials.add(new MutablePair<>(
                    partNumber,
                    sum
                ));
            }
        });
    });


    return plannedMaterials;
}
```

Comment: Hello, you might find better help at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, which is specialized in code reviews. :)

Comment: It would help if you add the definitions of the classes you are using (showing the signature of the methods so we can know what is what)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Sharon, using the right data structure for the right job will help a lot. In your case, consider using `Map<String, Double>` instead of `List<Pair<String, Double>>`. That alone will already simplify your code considerably.

```
protected List<Pair<String, Double>> extractPlannedMaterials(List<ProductionDataSummaryDTO> productionData) {
    Map<String, Double> result = new HashMap<>();

    productionData.stream()
        .map(ProductionDataSummaryDTO::getDailyProductionDatas)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .forEach(dailyData -> {
            String partNumber = dailyData.getProduct().getPartNumber();
            double sum = dailyData.getLineDatas().stream().mapToDouble(LineDataDTO::getPlannedQuantity).sum();

            result.compute(partNumber, (key, value) -> value == null ? sum : value + sum));
        }

    // return result as is or transform to list of pairs
}
```

The only added feature of the Stream API I've added is `Stream#map`, which will transform a stream of one object to a stream of another object. Use it instead of multiple `#forEach` calls.

Comment: can be further simplified with ``Collectors.groupingBy()`

Comment: thanks for your solution, but in your solution and one provided by Sharon, I get an error on dailyData.getProduct and dailyData.getLinesDatas, as it says, cannot resolve method, just wanted to tell that on hovering cursor over, dailyData it is a set, shouldn't it be a single element inside the set?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. As I previously explained, `Stream#map` transforms your stream from one object to another. So what happened was `Stream<ProductionDataSummaryDTO>` got transformed into `Stream<Set<DailyData>>`. I edited my answer and edited in `.flatMap(Set::stream)`. What this does is take the elements out of the set and put them into the stream itself: `Stream<DailyData>`. Now `#forEach` should behave like we expect it to. :)

Answer (score 1):

the code is extremely inefficient: for every item in DailyProductionDatas, you iterate over the list three times: the see if key exist, then to calcaulte new sum and once again the find the place to add.

`List` is simply not the suitable data structure for this processing. You better use `Map<String, Double>`. after you built the map, you can iterate once over it and translate to `List`.

and rule of thumb: don't use `LinkedList`, it's not worth it.

a more simplified version of the code from Sync:

```
Map<String, Double> plannedMaterialsMap = 
    productionData.stream()
        .map(ProductionDataSummaryDTO::getDailyProductionDatas)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             dailyData -> dailyData.getProduct().getPartNumber(),
             Collectors.summarizingDouble(dailyData -> dailyData.getLineDatas().stream().mapToDouble(LineDataDTO::getPlannedQuantity).sum()
        ));
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I guess you are missing that the sum has to be added to previous value

Comment: you guess wrong. "previous value" is the sum of previous entries of same key. this is exactly what `Collectors.summarizingDouble()` does

Comment: ok, my bad, thanks for guiding. Also, I am getting an error for dailyData.getProduct, as it says cannot resolve the method. It is considering dailyData as a set!!

Comment: what is the return value of `getDailyProductionDatas()`?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I think `List<DailyData>`

Comment: the return type is not Map<String, Double> rather - Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics> ?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the same results. It is clearer as each step is separated in smaller methods.

Also, as already mentioned by others, a `Map<String, Double>` is more efficient than a `List<Pair<String, Double>>`

First you need a method to sum a list of DailyData:

```
// make a list of all the LineDataDTOs in all the given DailyDatas
// and sum their plannedQuantity
double sumDailyData(List<DailyData> dailyDataList) {
    return dailyDataList.stream()
            .map(DailyData::getLineDatas)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .mapToDouble(LineDataDTO::getPlannedQuantity)
            .sum();
}
```

Using this method you can create a method to create a Map of each product with its daily sum

```
// Group your DailyDatas by partNumber
// and for each partNumber, sum the list of correcponding DailyDatas 
Map<String, Double> extractPartCountFromDailyData(List<DailyData> dailyDataList) {
    return dailyDataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dd -> dd.getProduct().partNumber))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e.getKey(),
                    e -> sumDailyData(e.getValue())));
}
```

Finally you use this method to extract your final Map

```
// Make a list of all the Maps returned by extractProductCountFromDailyData
// And merge them by adding the values for the same keys (using Map.merge)
Map<String, Double> extractPlannedMaterials(List<ProductionDataSummaryDTO> productionData) {
    return productionData.stream()
        .map(ProductionDataSummaryDTO::getDailyProductionDatas)
        .map(this::extractPartCountFromDailyData)
        .reduce(new HashMap<>(), this::mergeMaps);
}

// merges 2 maps by adding values for same keys
Map<String, Double> mergeMaps(Map<String, Double> acc, Map<String, Double> elem) {
    elem.forEach((k, v) -> acc.merge(k, v, Double::sum));
    return acc;
}
```